# i cant install GLPK and Rglpk package on Rstudio on mac

Tags: r

I can't install `GLPK` and `Rglpk` packages on Rstudio on mac and need help on it. I have been googling for an hour but to no avail. Really appreciate any advice on it.

Tried http://arnab-deka.com/posts/2010/02/installing-glpk-on-a-mac/ word for word but syntax doesnt work. cd and ./ configure doesnt exist. I probably am too new to R to realise that there is a change in its the syntax and i should adapt it?

brew install glpk

Error: unexpected symbol in "brew install"

cd ~/Downloads tar -xzf glpk-4.43.tar.gz

Error: unexpected '/' in "cd ~/"

There seemingly isnt an alternative to the solution posted in the link

Comment: What steps did you follow to install them? And what error messages did you get? Explain that by editing your question. Thanks

Comment: thank you for your suggestions to make my question more accurate and helpful to those who is looking out for new users. i have edited my question as requested.